# Xcode not building for iPhone after Upgrading it from 3GS to iOS 4.1?

Tags: iphone, ios4

i just upgraded my **iPhone 3GS** to **iOS 4.1** and also downloaded the latest **Xcode 3.2.4 and iOS sdk 4.1**....i was working on an application on previous sdk **iOS 4.0** but now when i build the project with new sdk xcode says ***No Provisioned iOS Device is connected***...do i need to install a new **provisioning profile** for the project?? i cant figure out why xcode wont build the application??

Comment: Is this an incremental upgrade or a clean restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up a new iPhone and did not restore it from a backup, your profiles have been lost. You need to reinstall them. Of course, you can use the same one again, as your unique device ID (UDID) does not change with a software update.

Connect your device, open the Xcode organizer (Windows -> organizer or Cmd+Option+O), select your device and click "Use for development". Then you can add your provisioning profile again.